# What are subscription applications?

Tags: iphone, android, blackberry, mobile-application

I heard this term recently. What are subscription applications(for a mobile platform). Does this term fall under standard usage? Are there any examples of such a mobile application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In subscription application you pay for right to use software for some period of time. E.g. application could cost for example $5 per month and as long as you keep paying, you can use the application.

I think that this is rather common term. I don't know about mobile apps but one example subscription based web app would be [Basecamp](http://basecamphq.com/). Another example would be [StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/pricing).

Comment: Thus, World of Warcraft would be a subscription application. (Although not a mobile one. Unless they have an app for that too.)

Answer (score 2):

Subscriptions on iPhone can be facilitated using [StoreKit](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: However, your app will not be accepted if its entire functionality falls under the subscription model.